# Angular8, Ng serve is very slow on my machine even for new/small projects

Tags: node.js, angular

Ng serve is taking around 20 minutes to start the application on my machine even if I restart machine.

Node version - v12.13.0
Npm version - 6.9.0
Angular-Cli version - 8.0.2
Angular Version - 8

System Configuration
Windows : 10/ 64 Bit
Ram : 8GB

Comment: I think it is issue from your computer. Try to install again your tools like nodejs, angular cli and start project again. Or Install again the operator system.

Answer (score 3):

This could be the issue with `@angular-devkit/build-angular` 
I had exactly the same issue tonight... and I found one solution ....

package.json/devDependencies :
I downgraded from `0.11`

`@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8"`,

and now it is fast (1.2 sec).... (without aot)
then I tested 0.8.8 ... it is OK (1.2 sec)
then I tested 0.10.7 ... slow for the first change (8 sec), then OK
then I tested 0.12.0-beta.0 .. it is not OK (11 seconds at 1st, 2nd, 3rd change)
so I go back to 0.10.7 ....

For me, it is still ~50 seconds for ng serve .. but then a change is 1 second instead of 12 seconds with 0.11
(with --aot it is 157 seconds to serve and between 50 and 157 for a basic change)

My Config :

Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8

**animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core**

forms, language-service, material, platform-browser

platform-browser-dynamic, router

**OR**

Try removing `node_modules` using

`rm -rf node_modules`

and reinstalling them again

`npm i` OR `npm install`

This may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but if I create new project and execute ng serve command it is taking same time for newly created projects, issues seems to be some specific version i am using, is it ??

Comment: Most of the time, compiling issue is related to the `angular-devkit` try downgrading, it may help you. There may be the issue of version compliance between node, angular & angular CLI!

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular is related ti your angular version, for example for  `"@angular/cli": "10.0.4"`  you should install ` "^0.1000.4"` version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`

Comment: Tried to downgrade the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version, but still no luck. I have somehow a big project, and it took 4-5 secs to live reload on angular 9, after I upgraded to Angular 11, it took 10-12 seconds to reload.. Are there any alternative solutions? thank you..